# How to turn off automatic completion for docker-compose.yml in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, yaml

Which setting do I have to disable?

I tried to google some solutions but either i am dumb or there are not really some solutions that can help me.

If I switch to a new line and write a "-" it should not do some kind of recommendation Like in the highlighted part in the picture.

[screenshot of vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFjxn.png)

Answer (score 0):

To turn off auto completions you need to do two things:

1. choose whether to disable auto completions entirely or based on specific file types.
2. Adjust the settings in `settings.json`

So for your case you need to disable auto completions for docker-compose.yml which gets `dockercompose` file type according to VSCode.

Then the second step is to adjust the settings to disable auto completion.

Add/modify the below settings in `settings.json`

```
"[dockercompose]": {
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,     
        "comments": false,  
        "strings": false    
      }
},
```

#### Tips

1. watch out if there are any settings that are conflicting with the same `dockercompose` file type
2. Check if your docker-compose.yml file's language is `dockercompose` or not using `cmd/ctrl+shift+p`,  select language mode and you should be able to see below
   [image]

#### Reference:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense